# Laravel: Get results from database based on lat long

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am new in laravel and using laravel 5.6 and I am working on the APIs. In the API result I want all the seller who are within the 50miles radius of the buyer with pagination.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$lat = Auth::user()->latitude;
$long = Auth::user()->longitude;
$products = DB::table('products')
                ->select(DB::raw('title, ( 
                        6371 * acos( cos( radians({$lat}) 
                    ) * cos( 
                        radians( `latitude` ) 
                    ) * cos( 
                        radians( `longitude` ) - radians({$long}) 
                    ) + sin( 
                        radians({$lat}) 
                    ) * sin( radians( `latitude` ) ) 
                ) 
            ) AS distance'))
            ->where('distance', '<', 50)
            ->paginate(20);

var_dump($products);
```

but I can't find the solution.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `->having('distance', '<', 50)`.

Comment: You do know modern versions of MySQL have the `POINT` data type for this use case, don't you? If you use that instead of storing the latitude and longitude as digits this will be a lot easier.

Comment: No, I did not know this. I need to look into this. It would be great help if you can send me an example for help.

Comment: @Ashish Well, I've only done that with PostgreSQL before so I can't give a specific example, but I found a Laravel package at https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial that aims to replicate the functionality of the package I used, so I recommend you look at that.

Comment: Oky thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, here is the query

```
$lat = Auth::user()->latitude;
        $long = Auth::user()->longitude;
        $products = Products::selectRaw('id, title, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(30.7062683) )
      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(76.7165878) )
      + sin ( radians(30.7062683) )
      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
    )
  ) AS distance')->orderBy('distance')->having('distance', '<', 100)->paginate(50);
        var_dump($products);
```

and then install and follow this package. It will help
https://github.com/justbetter/laravel-pagination-with-havings
I hope it will help someone in future. Happy Coding!!!